# Is publishing a web scraping script on Github to get data from a website to publish it on another place, illegal?

Tags: internet

I have written a script that fetches some information that is on a website and upon command it publishes it on another place. Is it illegal to publish it on Github and also if you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Screen scraping" is not illegal by definition. There might be situations and conditions where it is illegal, for example on websites which are protected by a password, or for text which is protected by copyright. But on it's own, there is no problem for you to write and publish a screen scraping script.

The U.S. Ninth Circuit Court of Appeals [allowed](https://searchengineland.com/does-the-9th-circuits-new-decision-in-hiq-vs-linkedin-open-the-floodgates-to-scraping-321687) HiQ Labs to scrape public data from the LinkedIn website. In an earlier [ruling](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-microsoft-linkedin-ruling-idUSKCN1AU2BV) by a federal judge, LinkedIn was even forbidden to use technology to prevent hiQ from accessing public profiles.

In a long legal process started May 2008 and ended September 2019 Ryanair lost from PR Aviation trying to forbid PR Aviation to scrape it's site. (Judgement in Dutch: [ECLI:NL:GHDHA:2018:61](https://uitspraken.rechtspraak.nl/inziendocument?id=ECLI:NL:GHDHA:2018:61)). (Ryanair was allowed to forbid scraping in it's general terms and conditions, but those terms and conditions were not legally binding to PR Aviation).